# Android - Simplifying Radicals

Tags: java

I am trying to make a calculator that performs the quadratic formula.

Currently if my result would be a decimal it returns NaN. (EDIT: Resolved)

Preferably I would like the result to be in an simplified radical form (i.e. √(99) = 3√(11) ).

How would I go about achieving this?

This is what I have so far.

```
// Do the math
private double mathCalcPlus(double varA,double varB,double varC) {
    return ((-varB + Math.sqrt(varB * varB - 4 * varA * varC)) / 2 * varA);

}

private double mathCalcMinus(double varA,double varB,double varC) {
    return ((-varB - Math.sqrt(varB * varB - 4 * varA * varC)) / 2 * varA);

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: √(99) = 3√(11) is an overkill, because factorization is slow and will require you to write additional code with no benefit.

Comment: I prefer this way since technically the decimal answer would be approximate.

On another note, my code will not produce a decimal number is simply produces NaN for results that are not whole numbers. So I think it would be helpful for me at least to fix this error in my code as well.

Comment: is double not the correct data type? If I use float it i get the following error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to float QuadraticFormulaActivity.java /Quadratic Formula/src/com/elite/quad line 54 Java Problem

Comment: Never mind I found I needed to change the data type of my a, b, and c variables when I declared them to float. Thanks Martin.

Comment: I would still like to produce a simplified radical form of the answers if anyone would try and help.

Comment: Further testing shows that I received the NaN results because the results would have been imaginary numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that might help as far as simplifying radicals go. Give it the unsimplified radical (let's say 850) and it should return the correct answer (5-/34). It also tries to recursively simplify what's left in the radical in case it needs to be broken down again.

This was written quickly so I'm sure there are edge cases I missed that will throw off the calculations but I hope it helps at least a little. Best of luck!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Radical {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter the unsimplified radical: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = scan.nextInt();

    recurse(input);

}

public static void recurse(int x) {

    System.out.println("Attempting to simplify -/" + x);

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        if ((i * (x/i)) == x) {
            //System.out.println(i + "<i rest>" + (x/i));
            a = i;
            b = x/i;
            if (Math.sqrt(a)%1==0) {
                if (a != 1) {
                System.out.println((int)Math.sqrt(a) + "-/" + b);
                count = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (count>0) {
        recurse(b);
    } else if (count==0) {
        System.out.println("Cannot simplify -/" + x);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. This worked, with a little editing of course to work with the ADK. Is the recurse needed? If so how would I impliment this in the ADK. I removed the recurse line and it seems to work quite well, but of course I will have to do more extensive testing to make sure it will work with all numbers.

Comment: The recurse isn't necessary, it was implemented as a failsafe incase I was getting strange numbers (which was very much the case earlier on). For implementing it in the ADK, I can't provide much help there. I'm a decent Java programmer slowly transitioning to Android dev so I still have a lot to learn. Good luck though!

Comment: Yeah I haven't found much on recursion for the android, but I haven't found any numbers yet that doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 1):

This works great!  However, I decided to add the top bar of the radical sign just for fun :D

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Radical {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter the unsimplified radical: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = scan.nextInt();

    recurse(input);

}

public static void recurse(int x) {

    System.out.println("                         ______");
    System.out.println("Attempting to simplify -/" + x);

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        if ((i * (x/i)) == x) {
            //System.out.println(i + "<i rest>" + (x/i));
            a = i;
            b = x/i;
            if (Math.sqrt(a)%1==0) {
                if (a != 1) {
                System.out.println("                      ______");
                System.out.println("                   " + (int)Math.sqrt(a) + "-/" + b);
                count = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (count>0) {
        recurse(b);
    } else if (count==0) {
        System.out.println("                  ______");
        System.out.println("Cannot simplify -/" + x);
    }

}

}
```